# how to update specified record in swift

Tags: swift

i save data by code :-

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Login", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    var newUser = Login(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    newUser.cardnamber = txtCardNamber.text
    newUser.mobilenamber = txtMobileNamber.text
    newUser.generationcode = GC
    newUser.status = "inactive"



    context.save(nil)

    println(newUser)
```

please i want way to update specified record ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to fetch Login. You can also use `predicate` to filter the `fetch result`.

Then, modify it and `save` the `context`.

**Like this example :**

```
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Login")
  do {
    let results =
      try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) // list of Login in array
    people = results as! [NSManagedObject]
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }

let firstLogin = results[0] as! Login // get the Login you wants
firstLogin.status = "active" // modify it

context.save() // save it
```

Enjoy ! ;)